# GitHubアカウント等でログインしたい

Tags: 機能の要求, アカウント

プログラマのためのサイトであるならば、GitHub等のアカウントでもログインできるべきではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

2020年2月現在、メールアドレスを元にしたアカウント登録の他に、GitHub, Google, Facebook の認証情報を用いたログインを行う事が出来ます。

既に作成済みのアカウントがある場合には、これら外部サービスのIDを追加の資格情報として紐付けることもできます。

参考:
[アカウントにログイン資格情報を追加または削除する方法は？ - ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Answer (score 4):

当サイトは「OpenID」を利用しています。残念ながら、GitHubのログインはOpenIdではありません。

この要求は英語版のサイトにも出ています：

[Authenticate to Stack Exchange using GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129555/authenticate-to-stack-exchange-using-github)

使える方法はあるらしいが、その質問の回答の中に次善策はあるらしいですが、その内容は確認していません。方法を探したら、皆様に教えてくれませんか？